# How do I add a menu item to a Pods admin menu?

Tags: plugin-development, menus, pods-framework

I'm writing a plugin that will send a notification message to an external queue whenever a menu item is clicked. This function is related to some customized data structures I made using the [Pods framework](http://pods.io/).

I'd like to add the menu item under the sub-menu for a certain Pod. The Pod is named "spotlight." Currently the only items in there are "All Spotlights" and "Add New"... I'd like to add a third item below these two.

In the code for my plugin, how do I add an additional menu item under this Pod's submenu?

Comment: What pod type? Custom Post Type?

Comment: An Advanced Content Type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add submenu items to a specific Pod's menu, try this:

`add_submenu_page( 'pods-manage-your_pod_name', 'My submenu item page title', 'My submenu item', 'manage_options', 'pods-manage-your_pod_name-my-submenu-item', 'your_callback_function' );`

Do this during the admin_menu action in WordPress, or alternatively do it during the 'pods_admin_menu' action.

Comment: This worked, though I had to replace 'pods-manage-your_pod_name-my-submenu-item' with "\__FILE__". That may be a consequence of the fairly ignorant design of my plugin. Also, as a note - calling this under "admin_menu" action resulted in having it as the first item under the submenu, while calling it under "pods_admin_menu" made it the last item.

Comment: Actually, I ended up having to add this under "pods_admin_menu_secondary_content", because adding it under "pods_admin_menu" has the side effect of making the pods admin menu disappear entirely from the sidebar.